# VUE: calculate 2d array with multple input

Tags: vue.js, multidimensional-array, reduce

In Vue, I'm inserting a value in a 2d array input field and calculating it per row, but the total value that is being returned only calculates the first row, and when I display, the computed value is all the same.

How can i calculate the inputted value so that the value will compute it per row and not just the first value?

```
<button @click="addFind">add</button>
<tr v-for="(classlist,index) in classlists" :key="'lab'+ classlist.id">
    <td>{{index +1}}</td>
    <td>{{classlist.student}}</td>
    <td v-for="(lab, i) in labs">
        <input v-model="lab.value[index]" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
    labs: [],
    classlists: [
      {  "student": "S1","id": 1 },
      {  "student": "S2","id": 2 },
      {  "student": "S3","id": 3 },
      {  "student": "S3","id": 4 },

    ],
  },
  methods: {
    addFind: function () {
      this.labs.push({ value: [] });
    }
  },
    computed: {
    studentTotalScores: function() {
      return this.labStudentScores.reduce(
        (acc, item) => acc + parseInt(item.value),
        0
      );
    }
    }
```

what i need:

```
NAME   | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | TOTAL   
name1  |   1    |   1    | 2
name2  |   2    |   3    | 5
name3  |        |        | 0
```

BUT THE OUTPUT:[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pailaka/ntbzp5m0/)

```
NAME   | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | TOTAL   
name1  |   1    |   1    | 2
name2  |   2    |   3    | 2
name3  |        |        | 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A computed property can only have a single value, you can't calculate it 'per row'.

What you can do is have the value be an array, with one entry per row.

The data structure you're working with is a bit of a pain as the arrays are transposed relative to the table. Still, it can be done with a bit of fighting.

First, in the template you'd add a suitable `<td>` to the end of the rows:

```html
<tr v-for="(classlist, index) in classlists" :key="'lab' + classlist.id">
  ... other tds not shown ...
  <td>
    {{ studentTotalScores[index] }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Then `studentTotalScores` would be:

```js
studentTotalScores: function() {
  return this.classlists.map((c, index) => {
    return this.labs.reduce((acc, item) => {
      const value = parseInt(item.value[index], 10) || 0
      return acc + value
    }, 0)
  })
}
```

I've added a base of `10` to `parseInt` to ensure consistent parsing, as well as `|| 0` so that `NaN` will be treated as `0`.

Comment: THANK YOU so much!!. I'm working for this code for how many days and it's 3 A.M now. I can finally sleep.